# Use login web session from webview to another activities

Tags: android, session, webview, openid

I develop an android application which makes login to a php openid server by using webview.

My problem is that once closed the activity of this webview, I need to make requests to the server from other enforcement activities that use the session logged from the first activity with the webview.

How can I use from other activities (not webview) the generated session on the server from the first activity (web view)?

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows:

I left openid login activity, just for that.

I created a new activity with a webview hidden from the user.

Since the activity where I want to perform the operation on the server with the login with openid, step right url as a parameter to the login activity and this in turn if the user was already logged in login or before, passing the same url the activity with hidden webview, which simply executes the instruction and returns to the main activity (shown only a very small period the user).

In this way it works, because since the webview if you can control whether the user is logged or not openid.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions is very general, so at best all I can do is give you a very general response. If you need to do stuff in the background over a long period of time, please checkout the [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) class. Also, with any mobile platform it's generally considered better practice to not use stateful web communication (i.e. communication that relies on sessions). Doing so is not very fault tolerant (and trust me, with **any** mobile platform your communication is going to need to be very fault tolerant). Instead you should look at making your communication RESTful. Here's a [great video](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) on developing RESTful applications for android.